# Coordinates adapted to Killing vector

Tags: differential-geometry, coordinate-systems, symmetry

Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold and let $k$ be a Killing vector of $g$, that is a vector field such that $\mathcal{L}_kg = 0$.

> I would like a general method for finding coordinates 'adapted' to
>   this Killing vector, that is, coordinates $(X^{\mu})=(X^i,\theta)$,
>   such that $$k=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$$

This is frequently referenced in physics papers, but I have no idea how to do this in principle or in practice. One often sees statements along the lines of 
*"...by choosing coordinates adapted to the isometry..."*, but no description of how to find such coordinates.

A concrete example would be helpful, so consider the following Riemannian metric, given in terms of coordinates $(x,y,z)$ as:
$$ds ^2 = dx^2 + (dy - xdz)^2 + dz^2$$
If I am interested in the Killing vector $k=\partial_x + z\partial_y$, how do I find coordinates adapted to this Killing vector? Note that the given coordinates are already adapted to the Killing vectors $\partial_y$ and $\partial_z$, but that's not what I'm asking.

Comment: The flow-box theorem guarantees the existence of an 'adapted' coordinates system to any non-vanishing vector field, be it Killing or not. In practice, the argument in its proof can yield explicit such coordinate systems (some possibly arbitrary choices have to be done). If I remember correctly, a proof of this theorem on manifolds is given in John M. Lee's book *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if I ca find a copy of that book. The choice of coordinates is certainly not unique, so I expect there are plenty of arbitrary choices to make along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A basic recipe: Choose a hypersurface $\Sigma$ transverse to $k$ (which will end up being $\{\theta = 0\}$) and a coordinate system $X^i$ for this hypersurface, and then transport $\Sigma$ along with $X^i$ using the flow of $k$.

In your example, an easy choice of $\Sigma$ is simply the coordinate surface $\{ x = 0\}$, which comes an obvious choice of coordinates $X^1 = y, X^2 = z$. Now we want to flow this along $k$; i.e. we want a map $(x,y,z) = \phi(X^1, X^2, \theta)$ such that $\phi(X^1, X^2, 0) = (0,X^1, X^2)$ and $$ \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial \theta} = \partial_x + z\partial_y.$$

Expanding this in components gives us $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial \theta} = 1, \; \frac{\partial y}{\partial \theta} = z, \; \frac{\partial z}{\partial \theta} = 0.$$

These equations along with the initial conditions $x = 0, y = X^1, z= X^2$ are easily integrated to yield $x=\theta, z = X^2, y = X^1 + \theta X^2$. Inverting these gives (an example of) the adapted coordinates you are looking for:

$$\theta = x, X^1 = y - xz, X^2 = z.$$